# How to duplicate 3 displays in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

I'm running a setup with 1 monitor and 1 computer with an RX470 where they are connected with 3 cables: DVI Dual Link, HDMI and DP. Both Windows and the AMD software correctly detect these connections - as 3 monitors. I switch between the input type via a button on my monitor. The problem should be the same with 3 different monitors and any connection types.

Windows allows me to:

- Disable any of them.
- Extend any of them.
- Duplicate any 2 of them.

However, I want to duplicate all 3. I read a bit around other sites and it seems to be a limitation of Windows 10, but I didn't find a definitive source. Some suggest that you have to use additional hardware like a splitter.

How to duplicate 3 (or more) displays?

Comment: You might need to do this using the AMD catalyst / crimson software. There should be an option there under eyefinity that lets you select what each monitor will display.

Comment: @Peter Interesting, but in my crimson software's Eyefinity I don't see an option to duplicate displays. There are quite elaborate ways to handle extended screen in various alignments and rotations, which is nice, but didn't see anything about duplication.

Answer (score 1):

This worked on my MSi laptop in WinVer 1809, using (1) the built-in display, (2) an Acer display via a DP & VGA adapter, and (3) a Samsung TV via HDMI:

- right-click on unused part of display
- select "Graphics Properties"
- select "Multiple Displays"
- check "Clone Displays" then
  "Select one or more active displays" (i had all 3 showing)
  Then all 3 displays showed the same screen/image.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup as the answer by Grant. On my MSI laptop with gt72S I use the Nvidia control panel:

1. Right Click on an empty part of the desktop
2. Select **NVIDIA CONTROL PANEL**
3. Select Setup Multiple Displays under the display section on the left navigation bar.
4. Right Click the display you want to duplicate to and select "Clone with". Then choose the display to duplicate. [image]

Answer (score 0):

For AMD Radeon system, right click on empty desktop,click AMD Radeon Software, settings wheel, display, insure all displays are visible to Global Display, click disable clone, then click enable clone. All three should be mirrored now.